# Return a double in Jest JS

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have a simple function like this that I want to test:

```
const saveAs = (fileName, content, contentType) => {
 const a = createDownloadLink(fileName, content, contentType)
 a.click()
}

export const createDownloadLink = (fileName, content, contentType) => {
 ...
 const a = document.createElement('a')
 ...
 return a
}

export default saveAs
```

I want to test that when I call `saveAs`, `createDownloadLink` is called, and `click` is called on the result.

I have tried mocking `createDownloadLink` and creating a spy on it. However, I can't find how to test click on the result:

Jest JS test:

```
  const createDownloadLink = jest.fn()
  saveAs('file.html', '<h1>hello</h1>', 'test/plain;UTF-8')
  expect(createDownloadLink).toBeCalled() // And return a double
  // expect(double.click).toBeCalled
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you have already answered your own question, but since you've stated you didn't like seperating your functionality in two files I may have an alternative solution. Since you are exporting both functions anyways may I propose you actually make both part of the same object? This would allow you to mock or spy on the module function easily. For example lets assume you have **`saver.js`**:

```
class Saver {
  saveAs(fileName, content, contentType) {
    const a = this.createDownloadLink(fileName, content, contentType)
    a.click()
  }

  createDownloadLink(fileName, content, contentType) {
    const a = document.createElement('a')
    return a
  }
}

const saver = new Saver();
export default saver;
```

Then you your test would look like this:

```
import saver from './saver'

describe('saveAs', () => {
  it("calls click on download link", () => {
    const click = jest.fn()
    saver.createDownloadLink = jest.fn(() => ({ click }));
    saver.saveAs('file.html', '<h1>hello</h1>', 'test/plain;UTF-8')
    expect(click).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this by creating an intermediate object that I use as a double.

Unfortunately, I had to separate my functionality into 2 files in order to use `jest.mock.

```
import saveAs from './index'
import createDownloadLink from './utils'
jest.mock("./utils");

describe('saveAs', () => {
  it("calls click on download link", () => {
    const downloadLinkDouble = {}
    const clickMock = jest.fn()
    downloadLinkDouble.click = clickMock
    createDownloadLink.mockImplementation(() => downloadLinkDouble)

    saveAs('file.html', '<h1>hello</h1>', 'test/plain;UTF-8')

    expect(clickMock).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```